# How to filter values of a variable

Tags: statistics, spss

For a school assignment I'm currently working with SPSS and want to analyse a data package we received from our client.
For instance; when I have got three variables, two being gender, age and the third one's the kind of drink respondents consume at the start of the day. In my analysis I only want to see the percentage of men between 20 and 30 drinking coffee. What function do I have to use to accomplish such thing?

Thanks in advance!
Emiel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of possibilities to start you off on SPSS syntax:

If you just want the answer to get this percent you could do this -

```
compute dr_cofee=(drink="Cofee").
value labels dr_cofee
0 "other drinks"
1 "cofee".
compute men20_30=range(age, 20, 30) and gender="men".
filter by men20_30.
freq dr_cofee.
filter off.
```

On the other hand you could generalize your analysis.
First create age groups, then analyze within each `AgeGroup`:

```
recode age (1 thru 19=1)(20 thru 29=2)(30 thru 39=3)([continue as needed]) into AgeGroup. 
value labels AgeGroup
1 "ages 1 - 19"
2 "ages 20 - 29". /* continue as needed.
sort cases by gender AgeGroup.
split file by gender AgeGroup.
freq Drink.
split file off.
```